# KVM switch - How to set up a script on OSX Lion to switch computers

Tags: macos

I am using a KVM switch to share a monitor between two laptops(one Win7 the other OSX Lion). I want to write a script for OSX Lion to run when I move my mouse into a hotcorner. The KVM switch I am using is a StarTech SV411KUSB and the only universal Hotkey sequence I know is ScrLk + ScrLk for it.

Primarily I want it so If I mouse over the Hotcorner with this script to run this sequence and switch to the next computer. But if it is possible, I would like it to switch to computer 3(Win7) as the first two are towers I won't be using in conjunction with OSX Lion. The KVM switch came with Windows only software for custom hotkeys so the windows side I can handle.

I am a new user when it comes to OSX but willing to learn.

RMDan